# How to separately style HTML5 apps using the Sencha framework for iOS and Android?

Tags: sencha-architect

App development in native Apps happens separately for iPhone and Android. But in HTML5 Sencha framework apps, the same HTML5 code is used. Should we use same visual styling for alert boxes or buttons for both platforms or should they look different depending on the platform?

Since the same HTML5 code is used, how do you to take care of different look and feel for both platforms? For example, the menu bar is at bottom for iPhone and for android it is at the top. Or for Android we need to hide the top back button Or how to style the alert boxes or buttons differently for both platforms?

Do we need to use different set of CSS files for iOS and for An?

I was going thru the kitchen sync Sencha application and it shows a very basic styling for alert boxes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the iOS/Android classes that Sencha Touch will add when detecting user agent. For example, if the device is running iOS the body element has the class "x-ios". For android it will be "x-android". This also applies for specific OS versions (ex: "x-ios-4"). Try overriding your user agent in Chrome and inspect the elements under different agents to get an understanding of the classes. Using these classes you can avoid multiple stylesheets and just set up the CSS accordingly depending on the class.

As for specific layout tweaks that cannot be performed with simple CSS - this is where profiles come into play (http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Profile). Set up a profile for Android and iOS, and use the launch function to manipulate specific components as needed.

Using these methods you should be able to keep things organized and minimize the number of separate files needed.